# Finding two consecutive paragraphs starting with the same word in ms word

Tags: microsoft-word, regex

I am trying to find all of those consecutive paragraphs, starting with the same exact word in Microsoft Word. The problem is that I cannot use ^p symbol with Regexp and don't see any other solutions. Could you please help me with this one? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `^013` instead of `^p`. This worked for me even when searching with wildcards.